# Ticks formatting in PGF, how to switch to completely decimal without powers of 10

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks

The ticks are sticking close to each other, almost overlapping. How to change the ticks from $2.5\cdot 10^{-2}$ to just $0.025$ without changing the dimensions of the diagram ?

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width={.5\textwidth},height={6 cm}}
\begin{axis}[ylabel={$\ln (I/I_0)$},
grid=major,
legend style={ legend pos= north east,},
xtick distance= .025,
]
\addplot[red, mark=square, only marks,]coordinates{
(0., 0.) (0.025, -0.842) (0.05, -1.671) (0.075, -2.217) (0.1, -2.823)};
\legend{$\theta = 11.0^\circ$; $\lambda = 0.77$ pm}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

The after a comment
[image]

Comment: Thanks!, I used ```yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed}``` but precision is reduced, so I get 0.03 instead of 0.025, any fix ?

Comment: `/pgf/number format/precision=3`

Comment: Didn't work it, gives as before

Comment: You need to use it combined (and for the x axis, of course): `xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=3}`.

Comment: Doesn't work, it gives the second image in the post above

Comment: @ Jasper Habicht, Though it did not impact the answer to this question, but worked like wonder for my plot after hours of trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width={.5\textwidth},height={6 cm}}
\begin{axis}[ylabel={$\ln (I/I_0)$},
grid=major,
legend style={legend pos=north east},
xtick distance=.025,
xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=3}
]
\addplot[red, mark=square, only marks,]coordinates{
(0., 0.) (0.025, -0.842) (0.05, -1.671) (0.075, -2.217) (0.1, -2.823)};
\legend{$\theta = 11.0^\circ$; $\lambda = 0.77$ pm}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]